# change BackColor on all forms Access VBA

Tags: forms, vba, backcolor

I've been trying to change the design of all my forms. For this I've created a function which opens each form, performs the changes, then saves and closes it. I can change every control accessing it with ControlType, but I don't know how to access and perform changes on the backcolor of a form. 
I've tried some ways but with no success, i tried
    me.formheader.backcolor
or even
    CurrentDb.Containers("forms").Documents(j).backcolor
I want to do this (which i did for one form):

```
Me.FormHeader.BackColor = RGB(225, 225, 255)
Me.FormFooter.BackColor = RGB(225, 225, 255)
Me.Detail.BackColor = RGB(242, 242, 242)
```

My code so far looks something like this: (it works for me)

```
Public Function SetFormDefaultsIleana()

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim wrkDefault As Workspace
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim frmName As String


    Set wrkDefault = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)


    For i = 0 To CurrentDb.Containers.Count - 1
        If CurrentDb.Containers(i).Name = "Forms" Then
        For j = 0 To CurrentDb.Containers("forms").Documents.Count - 1
        frmName = CurrentDb.Containers("forms").Documents(j).Name
        DoCmd.OpenForm frmName, acDesign
            For Each ctrl In Forms(frmName)

                If ctrl.ControlType = acLabel Then
                    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                    ctrl.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    '..  
             Next
        DoCmd.Save acForm, frmName
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frmName
        Next j

        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Forms module

`me.Form.Section(*).BackColor = RGB(55,155,255)`

and sections * are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835642(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: @IleanaProfeanu no problem. `Me` in the forms module refers to the form. since you have an outside macro you need to replace `me` to a reference to the actual form.